# Why does the command a-=2 fail?

Tags: bash, arithmetic

After executing the command `declare -i a=5`, the command `a+=2` succeeds, but the command `a-=2` fails. Can someone explain this strange behavior of bash?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Bash, arithmetic evaluation is done inside `(( ))`, e.g. `((i=i+3))`. From [Bash's man page (`man bash`)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html),

> **((expression))**
>
> The expression is evaluated according to the rules described below under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.

Both `-=` and `+=` are documented in the ARITHMETIC EVALUATION section, along with `= *= /= %= <<= >>= &= ^= |=`, and all work as you expect
**if** you use the arithmetic notation.

`+=` working without that notation is an exception described under PARAMETERS
section of the manual.

> When += is
> applied to a variable for which the integer attribute has been set, value is evaluated as an arithmetic expression and added to the variable's current  value,
> which  is  also  evaluated.

All in all, to get the desired behavior,

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i a=5
((a+=2))
echo $a
((a-=2))
echo $a
```

The output is 7 and 5.

Answer (score 22):

Bash doesn't have an `-=` assignment operator in the main shell syntax (arithmetic context is different, see below). That is to say, while you can use `=` to assign to variables, and `+=` to append to non-integer variables, or add to integer variables, there's no `-=`, `*=` etc. to go with them. The situation is the same in Ksh, where Bash's syntax is borrowed from (in this case, as in many others); and in Zsh, which also has similar features.

The other combined assignment operators apart from `+=` probably would make little sense for non-integers anyway, and since regular "string" variables are the most common ones, it's probably not worth it to have those operators in the main syntax. Especially since `var*=123` is also a glob, and `var/=123` looks like a path. But as said, `+=` does work for non-integers though:

```
$ foo=123; foo+=456; echo $foo
123456
```

The manual, as usual is somewhat brief on this, documenting the absence of `-=` only by omission. Section [3.4 Shell Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters) describes variable assignment and mentions `+=`, but no others.

Of course, in an arithmetic context (`$(( .. ))`, `(( .. ))` etc.), [all of `+=`, `-=`, `*=` etc. are available](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic):

```
$ foo=456; (( foo -= 123 )); echo $foo
333
```

Comment: Yes, += was added to ksh93 in ksh93j in 2000, zsh in zsh-4.1.0-dev-4 in 2002, bash in 3.1 in 2005, mksh in R40 in 2011. In mksh, += (outside of `((...))`) always does concatenation, even when the variable is declared as integer.

Answer (score 5):

Bash allows arithmetic evaluation implicitly when used with `+=` operator for a variable whose attribute is set to be integer type with `declare -i`. Without `-i`, it tells the shell to perform the "append" instead of "add" operation. The `-=` or other operators do not have a special meaning anywhere other than, when used inside arithmetic context.

See this excerpt from GNU bash man page

> When `+=` is applied to a variable for which the integer attribute has been set, value is evaluated as an arithmetic expression and added to the variable’s current value, which is also evaluated.

```
declare -i var=2
var+=2
printf '%d\n' "$var"
4
```

Without `-i`

```
declare foo=zoo
foo+=2
printf '%s\n' "$foo"
zoo2
```

Now for the other operators `*=`, `/=`, `%=`, `-=`, `<<=`, `>>=`, `&=`, `^=`,`|=` are all supported inside `$((..))`

```
foo=144; (( foo /= 12 )); printf '%d\n' "$foo"
12
```

One other behavior associated with `+=` when used with arrays `arr+=foo` appends the `foo` string to the element at the first index, while `arr+=(foo)` *appends* a new element `foo` to the array at the next index available.

Comment: Also note that if `a` is an array, `a+=foo` appends `foo` to the element of  indice 0 (setting it if it was previously unset), it doesn't append a `foo`  element to the array for which you need `a+=(foo)` (which adds the element at the end, not at the first free slot, remember  bash arrays are sparse). That's different from `zsh`.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers note *why* `a-=2` doesn't work (and that `((a-=2))` *will* work). I thought it worth recording that `a+=-2` will also work:

```bsh
$ declare -i a=5
$ echo $a
5
$ a+=2
$ echo $a
7
$ a+=-2
$ echo $a
5
```