# Why does the += operator fail to increment value?

Tags: shell, scripting

Why does += work as a concatenation in script?

```
while read t
do
    t+=2
echo $t
```

I get a 2 added to the end... Why?

Comment: Related: [Why does the command a-=2 fail?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/598986/why-does-the-command-a-2-fail)

Comment: See also https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2001/msg03001.html, where += was implemented in zsh (inspired from ksh93)

Comment: Why?  Because the implementers believed that a short form of `t=${t}2` might be welcomed by users.

Answer (score 17):

In most Bourne-like shells (ksh, bash,zsh), the `+=` operator works over three different variable types.

For a normal variable, a string variable, this happens:

```
$ a=hello
$ a+=3
$ echo "$a"
hello3
```

If the variable is defined as an integer type, or the operation is carried out in an arithmetic environment, the operator has the usual meaning that it also has in the c  language:

```
$ typeset -i a
$ a=31
$ a+=3
$ echo "$a"
34
```

or inside an arithmetic environment:

```
$ unset a
$ a=31
$ let a+=3           # an odd example to make you think!!.
                     # better use ((a+=3))
                     # or, in a POSIX sh: [ $((a+=3)) -eq 0 ]
$ echo "$a"
34
```

And, the `+=` is also used to add elements to an array (where the shell does have arrays).

```
$ unset a
$ a=()
$ a+=(one)
$ a+=(111)
$ printf '<%s> ' "${a[@]}"; echo
<one> <111>
```

So, the answer to your initial question:

> Why does += work as a concatenation in the script?

Is because `t` was a normal string variable (used outside an arithmetic environment).

Comment: [Instead of let expr, prefer (( expr ))](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2219)

Comment: You can also use `+=` to increment float variables in ksh93/zsh, or add elements to associative arrays in zsh, or to insert elements in the middle of arrays or strings in the middle of string variables in zsh (with `var[4]+=text`).

Comment: `aaa+=([key]=value)` works in Bash too to append to an associative array (and I guess it's the same in ksh), though I guess associative arrays are included in the part about adding to an array.

Comment: Except for floats, both bash and ksh could perform the same actions with `+=` AFAICT. @StéphaneChazelas

Answer (score 4):

In the feature-rich POSIX-like shells (ksh, mksh, Bash, zsh) the `+=` operator *is* a string concatenation operator when used on regular scalar variables. The result you're seeing is exactly what you would expect. If you want to increment `t`, you can do this:

```
while read t; do
  (( t+=2 ))
  echo $t
done
```

Or:

```
while read t; do
  t=$(( t+2 ))
  echo $t
done
```

Etc.

There is an extended discussion of this topic [here](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-increment-decrement-variable/).